# Solve the trigonometric problem about income

Tags: functions, trigonometry

> The monthly income of a store is
>   $$I=74500+43750\sin\frac{\pi t}6$$
>   $t$ is the time in months and $t=1$ is January.
>
> Find the number of months until the income exceeds $100000$.

I found the solutions of the equation with $I=100000$ as
$$t=2.413030,\ 3.586969$$
but I don't know how to interpret it.

Comment: Are you sure you mean $100\,000$ and not $10\,000\,000$? It seems that would make the question more interesting since $I$ is _always_ above $100\,000$.

Comment: According to WolframAlpha [all values of $t$ solve the equation $I=100000$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+7450000%2B4375000sin((pi*t)%5C6)%3E100000+for+t). Is this question definitely written correctly here?

Comment: I  just edited the problem, thanks.

Comment: @AP Alright, but I'm guessing you still want $74\,500$ instead of $7\,450$? Otherwise it never exceeds $100\,000$ ;-).

Answer (score 0):

If you plot the income as a function of t in a graph, besides a straight line at $y=100000$ you can see that the first time the income rises above $100000$ is in February. You can also show this if you write the income as $I(t)$ and then you show that $I(1)=96375$ and $I(2)=112388.61$.
The function only takes integers as argument since it asks for the monthly income.